# Find all dates in given range that have satisfy condition on rows in another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgresSql table that keeps track which dates have been processed:

```
CREATE TABLE history(
    date    TEXT,
    market  TEXT,
    type    TEXT,
    success boolean
);
```

On each next run, I need to find dates for match market and type and are either failed (success = false) or do not exist. Start day is provided and end is current day.

Example:

```
+------------+--------+------+---------+
|    date    | market | type | success |
+------------+--------+------+---------+
| 2019-08-02 | test   | left | TRUE    |
| 2019-08-03 | test   | left | FALSE   |
+------------+--------+------+---------+
```

Assume today is `2019-08-05`. Result for `market = test, type = left, start date = 2019-08-01` should be `2019-08-01, 2019-08-03, 2019-08-04, 2019-08-05`

My idea was to generate date series for the period and then to cross out successful dates for market/type

```
SELECT day::date
FROM generate_series(timestamp '2019-08-01', timestamp '2019-08-05', interval '1 day') AS t(day),
LATERAL (
    SELECT *
    FROM history
) as runs
WHERE (runs.market = 'test' AND runs.type = 'left') AND NOT runs.success = 'true'
```

but I just get all days in the interval - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/73b80/2/2 . Please advise!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, `not exists` is suitable:

```
select d.dte
from (select generate_series(min(h.date::date), current_date, interval '1 day') as dte
      from history h
      where h.market = 'test' and h.type = 'left'
     ) d 
where not exists (select 1
                  from history h
                  where h.date::date = d.dte and h.market = 'test' and
                        h.type = 'left' and not h.success
                 );
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8ab7e/4) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I get same results but.. twice http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/73b80/6/2 `2018-08-02` should not be in the result set.

Comment: @wzxsvm . . . I fixed a couple of typos and added a working SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for help!